# Updating table with all numbers before a decimal and 4 digits after decimal

Tags: string, oracle11g

I have the column below in some table

x

```
-81.384932
-127.4823922
-73.2933
-128.394449
-81.32173
-87.3215
```

I want to update this column so all the digits before the decimal are kept and only the first 4 digits after the decimal are also kept
The expected output should be something below

x_trim

```
-81.3849
-127.4823
-73.2933
-128.3944
-81.3217
-87.3215
```

Comment: update your tab set x = trunc(x,4);

Comment: I'd like to keep the 0 at the end if possible for example -125.90207 ends up being -125.902 when I want the result of -125.9020

Comment: This is just the *presentation* layer; use TO_CHAR with appropriate format mask, such as `to_char(your_value, '990D0000')`. Trailing zeros don't have any importance behind the decimal point.

Comment: select ltrim(to_char(trunc(to_number('-123.40007'),4), '9999999.0000')) from dual;